# Errors don't stop execution

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm coding using Python and Pyglet, and, as I just have starting the script, it is full of errors, which is normal.

What is less normal is that those errors don't stop execution of the script, even if they are 'basic python' errors. It isn't very bothersome, but a little, since it makes me outsee some errors.

For example, I got :

```
AttributeError: 'Win32EventLoop' object has no attribute '_next_idle_time'
```

(by the way, I don't know what this one means. It isn't the main subject of my thread but I'd gladly get answers for this one)

or :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

(A stupid bug I solved, but it should have stopped the script).

I use Eclipse + pydev, and never experienced that before. It may be pyglet related because it happened with my first pyglet attemps (before, I used pygame).

Thanks for answers,

Fred

Comment: My code is getting pretty long, and I don't want (yet) the errors to be fixed. I just want to understand why the script doesn't stop. I wonder if it's Eclipse related. Nonetheless, if you think it can help, I'll post it (but it's awful :) )

Comment: Something is catching your exceptions so they don't kill the program.  That something appears to be printing your exceptions as well.

Comment: This 'thing' is not my fact. For the time being, there's no exeptions handling in my code.

Comment: @Fred -- this might be somewhat common for GUI toolkits.  You'd have the same "problem" if you used `Tkinter`.

Comment: Yes, my guess is that Pyglet is catching exceptions in your event handlers so an error in one of them doesn't take down the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI application is probably running in some kind of loop. This event loop is catching exceptions for You and printing them out.

I recommend writing Your code the way You can unit-test small parts of your program e.g. classes or functions outside of the framework and then glue them together as GUI application. This work-flow will guarantee that you haven't overseen simple bugs just because mindlessly throwing new code into more-or-less working pile of existing code ;)

Read about [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) ;)

Comment: Thanks for explanations and advices :)