# Why doesn't an error stop a parallel python script

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing, exit

My intension is to raise an error and stop the Python script when certain condition met. Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
def my_func(some arguments):
    # some code
    if X.abs().max().max() > 1e50:
        print('------------ ERROR! line 287, extremely large X={} ----------------'.format(X.abs().max().max()), file=sys.stderr)
        print('selectedFeatures: '+('-'.join(sorted(list(selectedFeatures)))), file=sys.stderr)
        print('featurePool: '+('-'.join(sorted(list(featurePool)))), file=sys.stderr)
        print('p1: '+p1+',  p2: '+p2, file=sys.stderr)
        print('p1: '+p1+',  p2: '+p2, file=sys.stderr)
        print('X.shape={}X{}'.format(X.shape[0],X.shape[1]), file=sys.stderr)
        tmp = 1/0 # to create an error
    # some code

def caller_func():
    for-loop:
        # some code
        my_func(arguments)
        # some code
```

Part of the output is below, and the script keeps running even though there are errors.

```
# some stdout output content

------------ ERROR! line 287, extremely large X=3.130749212136059e+58 ----------------
selectedFeatures: <some_string>
featurePool: <some_string>
p1: <some_string>, p2: <some_string>
p1: <some_string>, p2: <some_string>
X.shape=133615X41
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py:-1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='my_file_1.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py:-1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='my_file_2.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//script_heavy_ga.py", line 332, in caller_func
    X, selectedFeatures, featurePool = my_func(p1, p2, X, X_original, selectedFeatures, featurePool)
  File "//script_heavy_ga.py", line 293, in my_func
    tmp = 1/0 # to create an error
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

# some stdout output content

------------ ERROR! line 287, extremely large X=1.1940462536258555e+75 ----------------
selectedFeatures: <some_string>
featurePool: <some_string>
p1: <some_string>, p2: <some_string>
p1: <some_string>, p2: <some_string>
X.shape=183025X41
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py:-1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='my_file_3.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py:-1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='my_file_4.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//script_heavy_ga.py", line 332, in caller_func
    X, selectedFeatures, featurePool = my_func(p1, p2, X, X_original, selectedFeatures, featurePool)
  File "//script_heavy_ga.py", line 293, in my_func
    tmp = 1/0 # to create an error
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

# some stdout output content
```

Parallel computing is used in my code `from multiprocessing import Pool`. Multiple instances of the function `caller_func()` run on multiple cores.

My question is, **why isn't the script stopped by the errors**? Some previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563629/errors-dont-stop-execution) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247492/prevent-error-from-halting-a-python-script?rq=3)) don't seem relevant. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258971/stop-python-code-without-an-error) might be relevant, but it did not answer why my code did not stop.

Comment: Why do you expect that? An exception in a spawned process kills that process, but it has no effect on any other proceeses.

Comment: "My question is, why isn't the script stopped by the errors?" I don't understand why you think it should be.

Comment: Another solution to terminate the script in a child process is to use `os._exit(1)`, **not** `sys.exit(1)`.